# Pgp key restoration from physical copy

Tags: gpgpu, pgp, openpgp

I used kleopatra to export my private key to a pdf. I printed the pdf and have a physcial copy. But i lost all the data on the computer and need to restore the key. How would i do so?

Tried to import to kleopatra after typing it all out. Thought it would work but it didnt